# Json4swift model class

Tags: swift, model

I am new to swift , using json4swift tool to make model class. I would like to know how to get data from model class , i managed to map the items to model class using below code.

```
  let responseModel = Json4Swift_Base(dictionary: searchResultsData)
```

My json responce folllows:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "categorys": [
    {
      "categoryId": 1,
      "categoryName": "Electricians                                      "
    },
    {
      "categoryId": 2,
      "categoryName": " Drivers                                          "
    },
    {
      "categoryId": 3,
      "categoryName": " Plumbers                                         "
    },
    {
      "categoryId": 4,
      "categoryName": "Carpenters                                        "
    },
    {
      "categoryId": 5,
      "categoryName": "Automobile works                                  "
    }
  ]
}
```

Json4swift tool made two classes namely Json4Swift_Base and Categorys class. I need to get from model class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn Swift, I would suggest you to forget json4swift.

First, you have to build your owns models: `Category` and `Response`

Category:

```
struct Category {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

Response:

```
struct Response {
    let success: Bool
    let categories: [Category]
}
```

Second, you want to initialize your models with a JSON. We are going to create a protocol for that:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String : Any]

protocol JSONDecodable {
    init?(dictionary: JSONDictionary)
}
```

Your models must implement this protocol, so we add extensions:

Category extension:

```
extension Category: JSONDecodable {
    init?(dictionary: JSONDictionary) {
        guard let id = dictionary["categoryId"] as? Int,
            let name = dictionary["categoryName"] as? String else {
                return nil
        }
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Response extension:

```
extension Response: JSONDecodable {
    init?(dictionary: JSONDictionary) {
        guard let success = dictionary["success"] as? Bool,
            let jsonCategoriesArray = dictionary["categorys"] as? [JSONDictionary] else {
                return nil
        }
        self.success = success

        self.categories =
            jsonCategoriesArray.flatMap{ jsonCategoryDictionary in
                Category(dictionary: jsonCategoryDictionary)
            }
    }
}
```

Now, you can write:

```
let response = Response(dictionary: jsonResponse)

if let response = response {
    let success = response.success
    let categories = response.categories
    let firstCategory = categories[0]
    // ...
}
```